# Text Field Update not Populating Case Description Long Text Field

Tags: field-update, update, long-text-area, text

I'm trying to create a Field Update Workflow where once the new case is generated, the description of the case will include text that shows:

1. First item
2. Second item
3. Third item
4. Fourth item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BR() can be used to create new line breaks in the text, so the formula used for this case should be:

```
"1. First item" & BR() & "2. Second item" & BR () & "3. Third item" & BR () & "4.Fourth item"
```